# Why are my Qt plugins not loading?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, plugins

I recently swapped from using MinGW to MS Visual Studio 2008 for my Qt application and in so doing the Qt image plugins and the Sqlite plugin no longer work on the QA computers.

Under MinGW it was just a case of putting the plugin dlls in imageforats folder but that does not appear to be enough in this case.

Has anybody else had this problem?

Comment: It is something to do with the SxS system and I am seriously thinking of recompiling Qt statically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I had to recompile as release and use the Microsoft Visual C re-distributable runtime.

I have lost the ability to debug on the QA machines but at least the plugins are working.